# QueryParser.parse causes TokenStream contract violation

Tags: lucene

I have inherited a project that was using Lucene 4.4.0 and I am trying to update it to use Lucene 4.6.1.

When the `parse` method of my class is called it invokes parse on Lucene's `org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser`. My class looks a bit like this:

```
public class SomeClass {

    String field;
    Analyzer analyzer;

    // omitted for brevity...

    public Query parse(String query) throws ParseException {
        QueryParserBase parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_46, field, analyzer);
        parser.parse(query);
    }
}
```

Since upgrading to 4.6.1 `parser.parse(query)` results in an exception like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: TokenStream contract violation: close() call missing
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.Tokenizer.setReader(Tokenizer.java:89)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer$TokenStreamComponents.setReader(Analyzer.java:307)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer$1.setReader(StandardAnalyzer.java:120)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer.tokenStream(Analyzer.java:183)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.QueryBuilder.createFieldQuery(QueryBuilder.java:207)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase.newFieldQuery(QueryParserBase.java:470)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase.getFieldQuery(QueryParserBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase.handleBareTokenQuery(QueryParserBase.java:842)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:358)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:257)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:181)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase.parse(QueryParserBase.java:120)
```

I am not familiar with Lucene's more recent API changes, however I don't seem to have access to the `TokenStream` to call `close()` or `reset()`.

So, how am I meant to solve this one?

Comment: Did you update *all* your Lucene jars to the new version?  I'd guess that you have a v4.4 analyzers-common or queryparser jar in your classpath.

Comment: Yes I have updated all jars, my dependencies are managed by Ivy.

Comment: You must be using custom analyzer and/or tokenizer. Please post the relevant code.

Comment: The `analyzer` is an instance of class `org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer`. Interogating the object with the debugger, I can see that its reuse strategy is set to `Analyzer.GlobalReuseStrategy` and it appears to be using `org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizer`

Comment: Can you post a trimmed-down-to-basics, self-containing example demonstrating the problem?